# Replicating Excel's CHIDIST function in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, excel, oracle11g, statistics

I'm attempting to replicate the functionality of an Excel workbook in Oracle. One of the formulae on the worksheet uses CHIDIST, which "Returns the one-tailed probability of the chi-squared distribution". I can't see a similar function in Oracle anywhere! Am I going to have to write my own CHIDIST function?

Here's a link to Excel's documentation on CHIDIST: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/chidist-HP005209010.aspx

I've already worked out the Chi Square and Degrees of Freedom.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right tail probability... nice...

In oracle you can embedded java code into stored procedures and functions. The best way is to 
use proper java class and call it from oracle's function. It is not that hard:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chfive.htm
http://jwork.org/scavis/api/doc.php/umontreal/iro/lecuyer/probdist/ChiDist.html

That is all I can do for you:

```
DECLARE
    l_value_to_evaluate NUMBER (10, 3) := 18.307;  /* X; Value at which you want to evaluate the distribution */
    l_degrees_freedom   NUMBER := 10;              /* Degrees of freedom */
    l_number NUMBER;

    FUNCTION is_number(str_in IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER
    IS
        n NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        n := TO_NUMBER(str_in);

        RETURN 1;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
            RETURN 0;
    END;
BEGIN
    -- If either argument is nonnumeric, CHIDIST returns the #VALUE! error value.
    l_number := is_number(l_value_to_evaluate);
    l_number := is_number(l_degrees_freedom);

    -- If x is negative, CHIDIST returns the #NUM! error value.
    IF SIGN(l_value_to_evaluate) = -1 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20998, '#NUM!');
    END IF;

    -- If degrees_freedom is not an integer, it is truncated.
    l_degrees_freedom := TRUNC(l_degrees_freedom);

    -- If degrees_freedom < 1 or degrees_freedom > 10^10, CHIDIST returns the #NUM! error value.
    IF l_degrees_freedom < 1
    OR l_degrees_freedom > POWER(10, 10) THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20997, '#NUM!');
    END IF;

    -- CHIDIST is calculated as CHIDIST = P(X>x), where X is a χ2 random variable.
    /* Here the integral's implementation */
EXCEPTION
    WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20999, '#VALUE!');
END;
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your suggestion! I'd rather have a solution that didn't involve having to do this - it seems like it would be just as easy to create my own PLSQL function which worked it out. I would really like to know if there is in fact a way to do it in pure Oracle SQL, using existing functions. If not, then I may have to either implement your suggestion or translate existing code into PL/SQL.

Comment: I would help you but I have never implemented a integral.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CHIDIST to do a chi-squared test, the [`STATS_CROSSTAB`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions170.htm#SQLRF06317) function might be a different means to the same end.  It will calculate the chi-squared value, significance, or degrees of freedom for two sets of paired observations.